# Выборка среди многих записей SQL

Tags: выборка, sql

К примеру в таблице 1 000 000 записей, как будет вести себя выборка:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `group` = '4';
```

К полю **group** добавлен индекс.

Чисто для себя узнать. И если медленно, какие способы ускорения существуют? На просторах интернета толкового так ничего и не нашёл.

Comment: В нормальном sql (mysql -- исключение) обматерит на тему, что id не является аргументом агрегатной функции.

Comment: @alexlz, и как быть? Что делать?

Comment: А там дальше уже есть совет -- внести поле id в предложение group. Или брать агрегатную функцию от id, например min(id)

Comment: @alexlz `group` - это такое неудачное имя столбца, а не кусок group by.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov позор на мои седины. То, что писал выше -- в мусор.

Comment: @alexlz, и как внести id в предложение group? :(

Comment: @ModaL А Вам это не надо. Я ночной порой вопрос не разглядел (@Yura Ivanov подсказал). А внести -- просто, но, поскольку у Вас группировки нет, то об этом можно и не думать.

      SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `group` = '4' GROUP BY id;

Есть разные средства анализа запросов. Посмотрите, что они выдают. Если назовёте сервер, то народ, я думаю, подскажет, какие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если group в индексе то на скорость будет влиять только общее количество записей с group=4 и то это будет влиять на скорость фетча а не на скорость выполнения запроса.

Comment: @Чад, т.е выборка будет быстрой?

Comment: Ну тут сложно сказать, зависит от субд, но абстрактно поиск по индексу быстрая операция.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте id к индексу по group, чтобы не выполнялась лишняя операция чтения.

Comment: @msi, как понять "id к индексу по group"?

Comment: SQL Server имеет предложение INCLUDE в операторе CREATE INDEX. Т.е. индекс может содержать дополнительные столбцы, по которым индексация как таковая не выполняется. Когда в запросе присутствуют только такие столбца, не нужно обращаться к самой таблице - все берется из индекса.
Я не знаю специфики MySQL, но и без этой возможности можно сделать составной индекс {group, id} и провести эксперименты.